# Calculating quantile of distribution function

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I'm having a problem with a statitics example.

The calculation for my quantile is not difficult. But I'm wondering which part of my function I need to use.

Let's say my distribution function is like:

$$ F(x)=\begin{cases} \frac {1}{4} x - \frac {3}{2} & \mbox{for } 6 \le x \le 8 \\
\frac {5}{2} - \frac {1}{4} x & \mbox{for } 8 < x \le 10 \\
0 & \mbox{else} \end{cases} $$

Now. If I need to calculate a Quantile - 0.7 or 0.3 - I know that $ F(x) = 0.3 $, but how do I know which part of my function I need to use?

Comment: Find out what $F(x)$ is at the boundary (in the continuous case). Here it is $1/2$. So for the $70$-th percentile, for example, we know it occurs past $8$.

Comment: hm? I dont get it? Which boundary? How do you come up with 1/2?!

Comment: Plug in $x=8$ into either expression.

Comment: ah you mean like I test all boundaries at F(X) and check which quantile I have at this particular x value and so i know where to look for?

Comment: The only important "transition" from one formula to another occurs at $x=8$. By finding $F(8)$, which turns out to be $1/2$, you discover that if you want, for example, to find out where $F(x)=0.2$, you need to find where $\frac{1}{4}x-3/2=0.2$. If on the other hand you want to find out where $F(x)=0.9$, then since $0.9\gt F(8)=1/2$, you need to find out where $\frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{4}x=0.9$.

Answer (score 0):

> The only important "transition" from one formula to another occurs at $x=8$. By finding $F(8)$, which turns out to be $1/2$, you discover that if you want, for example, to find out where $F(x)=0.2$, you need to find where $\frac{1}{4}x-3/2=0.2$. If on the other hand you want to find out where $F(x)=0.9$, then since $0.9\gt F(8)=1/2$, you need to find out where $\frac{5}{2}-\frac{1}{4}x=0.9$.

-- André Nicolas